# The element type xs:element must be terminated by the matching end-tag </xs:element>

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an error message on my XML Schema.  To start, here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="customer.xsd">
    <name>
        <first>Bob</first>
        <MI>H</MI>
        <last>Jones</last>
    </name>
    <cnum>007389</cnum>
    <mail_a>
        <line1>12345 Mockingbird Lane</line1>
        <city>Omaha</city>
        <state>NE</state>
        <zip>68123</zip>
        <country>USA</country>
    </mail_a>
    <deliver_a>
        <line1>12345 Mockingbird Lane</line1>
        <city>Omaha</city>
        <state>NE</state>
        <zip>68123</zip>
        <country>USA</country>
    </deliver_a>
    <member_date>1995-10-15</member_date>
    <l_order_date>2003-08-02</l_order_date>
</customer>
```

And here is my schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="customer"/>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="name"/>
      <xs:element ref="cnum"/>
      <xs:element ref="mail_a"/>
      <xs:element ref="deliver_a"/>
      <xs:element ref="member_date"/>
      <xs:element ref="l_order_date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="MI" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="cnum" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="zip" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="member_date" type="xs:date"/>
<xs:element name="l_order_date" type="xs:date"/>

<xs:element name="name">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="first"/>
      <xs:element ref="MI"/>
      <xs:element ref="last"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

 <xs:element name="mail_a">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="line1"/>
      <xs:element ref="city"/>
      <xs:element ref="state"/>
      <xs:element ref="zip"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>


<xs:element name="deliver_a">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="line1"/>
      <xs:element ref="city"/>
      <xs:element ref="state"/>
      <xs:element ref="zip"/>
      <xs:element ref="country"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The error that I'm getting is

> The element type `xs:element` must be terminated by the matching
>   end-tag `</xs:element>`

It appears that it doesn't like line 55 for some reason (element ref="line1"), which has a closing tag on it.

The XML file says that I'm missing the xs:schema end tag.  Well, there it is...
The editor that I'm using is oXygen.

Any thoughts? I've been fiddling around with it forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the premature closing of the `customer` element declaration that @randominstanceOfLivingThing mentioned, you must change

```
xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

to

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

in your XML, then your XSD will be found and your XML will validate successfully.

Here are the entire, corrected XML and XSD files:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="try.xsd">
  <name>
    <first>Bob</first>
    <MI>H</MI>
    <last>Jones</last>
  </name>
  <cnum>007389</cnum>
  <mail_a>
    <line1>12345 Mockingbird Lane</line1>
    <city>Omaha</city>
    <state>NE</state>
    <zip>68123</zip>
    <country>USA</country>
  </mail_a>
  <deliver_a>
    <line1>12345 Mockingbird Lane</line1>
    <city>Omaha</city>
    <state>NE</state>
    <zip>68123</zip>
    <country>USA</country>
  </deliver_a>
  <member_date>1995-10-15</member_date>
  <l_order_date>2003-08-02</l_order_date>
</customer>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="cnum"/>
        <xs:element ref="mail_a"/>
        <xs:element ref="deliver_a"/>
        <xs:element ref="member_date"/>
        <xs:element ref="l_order_date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="MI" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="cnum" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="zip" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="member_date" type="xs:date"/>
  <xs:element name="l_order_date" type="xs:date"/>
  <xs:element name="name">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="first"/>
        <xs:element ref="MI"/>
        <xs:element ref="last"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="mail_a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="line1"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="state"/>
        <xs:element ref="zip"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="deliver_a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="line1"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="state"/>
        <xs:element ref="zip"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after the schema declaration you closed the customer element:

Incorrect schema element:

```
    <xs:element name="customer"/>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="cnum"/>
            <xs:element ref="mail_a"/>
            <xs:element ref="deliver_a"/>
            <xs:element ref="member_date"/>
            <xs:element ref="l_order_date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Correct schema element:

```
    <xs:element name="customer">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="cnum"/>
            <xs:element ref="mail_a"/>
            <xs:element ref="deliver_a"/>
            <xs:element ref="member_date"/>
            <xs:element ref="l_order_date"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate the help. Once I removed the end tag my schema validates but my XML does not.  I get the message "
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'customer'."  I will note, namespaces slightly confuse me, and I am guilty of being a beginner.

Comment: @Itsonlyme: If you now have a different problem, it belongs in a new question. Your question here has been answered.